# Percentile function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, percentile

Is there a convenient way to calculate the percentile of a column based on the values of other columns in a data frame. 
i.e. the 10th percentile of prices for each type of toy

I have a method by which I can get my answer but it is very long winded and won't work well on larger datasets

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Toy': ['Truck', 'Truck', 'Truck', 'Barbie', 'Snake', 'Barbie'], 
    'Colour': ['Blue', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Pink','Green','Red'], 
    'Price': [4, 6, 8, 5, 9, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

df2 = df.groupby(['Toy'])['Price'].agg([np.sum,np.mean, lambda x:np.percentile(x,q= 10)]).reset_index()
df2

df_result = pd.merge(df,df2, on= 'Toy', how='left')
df_result
```

Which outputs - (lambda being the variable of interest)
[image]

Comment: I don't see how much smaller it can get than `df.groupby("Toy").Price.apply(np.percentile, 10)`.. but idk. Why doesnt it work well ? too slow ?

Comment: I don't want to reduce the dimensions of the dataset - what I would like is to have a column added to the end of the table that shows the 10th percentile for all items of the same class i.e. the same toy type. I've just added a picture to show the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you don't need to make this so complicated (creating another df, using `merge` etc).

You can simply do

```
res = df.groupby("Toy").Price.apply(np.percentile, 10)
```

And use the indexes to match results

```
df = df.set_index("Toy")
df.loc[:, "Percentile"] = res
df.reset_index()
```